# How to implement e-mail autocompletion with Twitter's bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I.e. how to modify [Twitter's bootstrap typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) code to ignore everything before symbol @? So, when user inputs e-mail, once @ is input, we should suggest domain for him from pre-defined list (like gmail.com, yahoo.com, att.net etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it without some additional magic. Fortunately this magic is pretty easy and fun. I really enjoyed solving this puzzle :)

Consider this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyxMh/2/) I've created.

```
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.select = function() {
    var val = this.$menu.find('.active').attr('data-value'),
        newVal = this.$element.val().replace(/@.*$/, '@' + val);
    this.$element.val(newVal);
    this.$element.change();
    return this.hide();
};

$('#email').typeahead({
    source: ['gmail', 'hotmail', 'yahoo'],
    matcher: function(item) {
        var m = this.query.indexOf('@'),
            search;

        if (!~m) {
            return false;
        }

        search = this.query.substr(m + 1).toLowerCase();
        return search.length && ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(search);
    }
});
```

First of all you need to define your custom `matcher` function in order to define what values are considered fitting. It is easy. The complicated part is that you need to change Typeahead prototype in order to make plugin to set correct new value of the input field: e.g. not `gmail`, 'yahoo', but full email address like `tomas@gmail.com`, etc.

Comment: Nice ;) Thanks for coding it. Is there any way to show full e-mail (tomas@gmail.com, tomas@mail.com) in dropdown? (so user will not be confused that chosen value (gmail.com, mail.com) will replace what he inputs (tomas)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, dfsq! How can I make these `matcher` and `render` fields applicable just to one field, since I have one e-mail field and many other fields, where standard `typeahead` should work. Please see this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hyxMh/9/

Answer (score 0):

Actually we don't need to make some extend, Just use the ajax function like this.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (typeahead, query) {

     var con = $('#input1').val();
     var atpos = con.indexOf('@');
     if(atpos==-1){
        return [con+'@gmail.com',con+'@sina.com',con+'@qq.com',con+'@126.com'];
     }else if(atpos>0){
         //get value before @
         var tmp = con.substr(0,atpos);
         return [tmp+'@gmail.com',tmp+'@sina.com',tmp+'@qq.com',tmp+'@126.com'];
     }else{

     }
     //return ['alpha','beta','bravo','delta','epsilon','gamma','zulu'];
    }
});
```